# Searching for non uniform time mentions in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble with my python script

```
import re
text = 'asd;lkas;ldkasld12:00 AMalskjdadlakjasdasdas1:24 PMasldkjaskldjaslkdjd'
banana = re.findall ('\d\d:\d{2} \wM', text)
print (banana)
```

I'm trying to search for any mentions of time, but I can't find the strings if they are single digit in the text.

Comment: Try `\d?\d:\d\d`.

Comment: date= re.findall("\d{1,2}:\d{2)", text)  might work. the {1,2} gives an upper and lower limit to the amount of digits it should expect

Comment: @Peter add it as an answer. Your answer is correct

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for exactly 2 numbers with `\d\d`. You need to change it to:

```
'\d{1,2}:\d{2} \wM'
```

This will look for 1 or 2 numbers. Also, I suppose that you want to match `AM` or `PM` with `\wM` in that case you could use:

```
'\d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M'
```

Comment: This is very helpful I didn't know you could be more specific with your searches, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`date= re.findall("\d{1,2}:\d{2) [A|P]M", text)` 
The {1,2} gives an upper and lower limit to the amount of digits it should expect.
The [A|P]M gives it specific instruction to find either AM or PM. Reducing the risk of false positives.

If you want some more information on what regex can do here is the documentation that helped me learn: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this iswhat you are looking for:

`banana = re.findall ('\d?\d:\d{2} \wM', text)`